# Why does my exported FBX "grow" a face on my object once exported into UnrealEngine4?

Tags: objects, export, faces, .fbx, unreal-engine

I made a cleaning cart in blender using quite a few Boolean modifiers.

Originally I had the same issue within blender, but after just messing around with the object I was able to fix it.

Now once I export the object as an FBX into UE4, it mysteriously "grows" a face over the handle area.

I have exported the cart with just one (1) receptacle and had no issues, but as soon as I shift D the receptacle part to the other side and join all three (3) objects I have this issue.

I have also unwrapped the UV's multiple times and feel like they are at the most optimized they can be.

[image: Cleaning cart in Blender]

[image: Cleaning cart in UE4]

Other questions on this site related to this issue did not help me.